# Jetty directory listing not working as expected

Tags: java, jetty, embedded-jetty

Here is my setup:

```
    // Static resource servlet
    ServletHolder defaultServletHolder = new ServletHolder("Default-Servlet", DefaultServlet.class);
    defaultServletHolder.setInitParameter("dirAllowed", "true");
    defaultServletHolder.setInitParameter("resourceBase", "/some/absolute/path");

    //Context
    ServletContextHandler context = new ServletContextHandler(ServletContextHandler.SESSIONS);
    context.setContextPath("/");
    context.addServlet(defaultServletHolder, "/*");

    Server server = new Server(8080);
    server.setHandler(context);
    server.start();
```

The first request works perfectly, but for every subsequent request, regardless of browser, the request never returns and chrome (inc. dev tools) just tells me its loading.

Comment: What version of Jetty?

Comment: @JoakimErdfelt  9.3.0.M2